# How to prove that a function has directional derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I want to prove that the function the given function has directional derivative for all $x\in\mathbb{E}^2$ and for each $v\in \mathbb{E}^2 \setminus \{0\}$.

$$
    f(x)= 
\begin{cases}
    \frac{x_1^2x_2}{x_1^4+x_2^2},  & \text{if } x \in \mathbb{E}^2 \setminus \{\mathbf{0}\}, \\      
    0,              & \text{if } x = \mathbf{0}.
\end{cases}
$$

I was thinking about trying to let $x\in\mathbb{E}^2$ and $v\in\mathbb{E}^2 \setminus \{0\}$ and try to show that 
$$D_vf(x) = \lim_{t\to 0}\dfrac{f(x+tv)-f(x)}{t}$$
exists. But I ended up getting really messy equation. Also, if the function has directional derivatives for each $x\in\mathbb{E}^2$, does this mean it is also differentiable? Also, does existence of all partial derivatives respect to each $x\in\mathbb{E}^2$ imply the function is differentiable?

Comment: See first https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/827382/directional-derivatives-exist-for-function-neither-continuous-nor-differentiable?rq=1

Comment: @MyGlasses Doesn't this only try to show that the directional derivative exist at $(0,0)$ and not for all $x\in\mathbb{E}^2$?

Comment: let $x_2 = x_1^2$ and check out the limit as $x_1$ goes to $0.$  Is the function continous?

Comment: For $p\neq(0,0)$ directional derivative is $\nabla f(p).\vec{v}$ with unit $\vec{v}$.

Comment: @DougM If I let $x_2=x_1^2$, then the function would not be continuous at $(0,0)$ but this shows that function is not differentiable at $(0,0)$. I want to show that the directional derivative D_vf(x) exists at each $x\in\mathbb{E}^2$ for each $v\in\mathbb{E}^2\setminus \{0\}$

Comment: @MyGlasses I am sorry but what is $\nabla f(p).\vec{v}$? Is this the matrix of partial derivatives?

Comment: It is $f_x(p)v_x+f_y(p)v_y$ for $p\neq(0,0)$ and unit vector $v=v_x\vec{i}+v_y\vec{j}$

Comment: Sometimes, the equations are messy. It’s not all that difficult to grind through.

Comment: For origin use definition $D_vf(0) = \lim_{t\to 0}\dfrac{f(0+tv)-f(0)}{t}$.